# SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERRO: coluna alis.nome_coluna não existe LINE 1:

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, symfony

Eu tenho uma página em meu sistema que faz uma transferência de arquivos, ele só faz um update na tabela. Eu copiei as linhas desse código e pus para funcionar em outra página, alterando somente os nomes dos campos e da tabela.

Estou usando para desenvolvimento em PHP o framework Symfony 1.4 com MVC. No action da função original tem dois actions um que faz abrir a página e outro que faz o código do update. No action da outra página, eu copiei o action que faz a página abrir e o action do código que faz o update, alterei o nome dos campos e da tabela.

A minha função, como eu disse, pega o número do procedimento (página dos códigos originais) e traz junto para quem o procedimento foi cadastrado. No banco de dados tem uma coluna booleana `transferido` que recebe padrão `false` e se for alterado passa a ser `true` – e se for `true` eu digo no meu código para ele inverter os valores.

Eu fiz a mesma coisa para a outra página. Se eu não criar a coluna `transferido_den` (nova coluna booleana) o meu botão que faz a função de abrir a página para transferência, funciona tudo certo, porém não altera nada por que não tem uma coluna na tabela criada para receber o valor `true`. Se eu criar a coluna `tansferido_den` o meu sistema não carrega os dados e aparece o erro dizendo que a coluna não existe.

Meu código do action é esse:

```
public function executeTransferir(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->forward404Unless(
        $denuncias = Doctrine::getTable('Denuncias')->find(array($request->getParameter('id'))), 
        sprintf('Object denuncias does not exist (%s).', 
        $request->getParameter('id'))
    );

    $this->forward404Unless($this->getUser()->hasPermissionFor('denuncias','editar'), 'Você não possui permissão para executar esta ação!');

    $params = $request->getParameter("denuncias");

    Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('denuncias d')
        ->set('d.id_conselho', '?', $params['id_conselho'])
        ->set('d.transferido_den', 'NOT(d.transferido_den)')
        ->where('d.id = ?', $request->getParameter('id'))
        ->execute();

    return $this->renderText('<script>parent.window.location.href = "' . $this->getController()->genUrl('@denuncias') . '";</script>');
}
```

Eu não sou o criador do sistema, só estou dando manutenção (sou estagiário). Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Estava dando erro por causa da database que eu estava chamando. Existiam 2 com nomes parecidos, eu estava criando na db que não estava sendo chamada no meu arquivo, por isso o erro.

Answer (score 0):

tente colocar um ? como na linha acima entre os parametros:
 ->set('d.transferido_den', '?', 'NOT(d.transferido_den)')

provavelmente funcione.

Comment: Eu acho que não é isso, eu fiz aqui e o erro continua o mesmo. :T